# EF Core TPT and using principal key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I am trying to model hierarchy in EF.

```
public class HierarchyNode
{
     public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteNode : HierarchyNode
{
     public long MainExternalId { get; set; }

     public long ExternalId { get; set; }
     public ConcreteNode ExternalConcreteNode { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use [TPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration) that EF offers. But I have an issue with setting a principal key.

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ConcreteNode> builder)
{
     builder
        .HasOne(x => x.ExternalConcreteNode )
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<ConcreteNode>(x => x.ExternalId)
        .HasPrincipalKey<ConcreteNode>(x => x.MainExternalId) // problem
        .IsRequired(false)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

These IDs come from external system and I need to create relations between them. When I remove inheritance, it works, but with inheritance I get this error:

> The CLR property 'MainExternalId' cannot be added to entity type 'HierarchyNode' because it is declared on the CLR type 'ConcreteNode '.

Is there any way how to set a principal key within derived type? Or I should to do it in different way?

Thanks for any advice

**// UPDATE**
Configuration for HieararchyNode looks like:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<HierarchyNode> builder)
{
     builder.ToTable(nameof(HierarchyNode));
     builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
}
```

When I move *MainExternalId* to base class, it works. But the key is specific for *ConcreteNode*, so it's not suitable to move it there.

Comment: What is the PK on the ConcreteNode table? By default EF configures one-to-one relationships by joining PKs between tables. It can be configured to use a many-to-one relationship with a FK and treat it as a one-to-one, but it still needs to join on the PK on one side or the other.

Comment: I've updated question with configuration of HierarchyNode. There is set PK which is also used as PK for ConcreteNode. I found same issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21974), so it looks like known issue.

Comment: Yes, an alternate key breaks TPT. EF creates two disconnected tables. BTW, I don't get the error using EFC 6.

Comment: Do you really need to map HierarchyNode to a database table?  If you just leave it out of your model, you'll get a single table for ConcreteNode.  And any other HierarchyNode subtypes will simply be stand-alone tables.

Comment: @GertArnold thank you, problem was that I had DB sets for base class and each subclass, when I removed DB set for base class, it's working.